# Rename parameterized testMethod

Tags: java, testng

I want to rename a test method in one of my classes that uses a large number of parameterized objects.

For example, if I have a test method set up like so:

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest 
{
    static class data_class{
        public String name;
        public String two;
        public data_class(String name, String two){
            this.name = name;
            this.two = two;
        }
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "prov1")
    public static Object[] prov1(){
        return new Object[] { new data_class("one", "one"), new data_class("two", "two") };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="prov1")
    public void testApp(data_class input)
    {
        System.out.println(String.format("Name: %s Two: %s", input.name, input.two));
    }
}
```

The output of a test run (in Eclipse, surefire xml reports are similar) shows this output, notice the method name is testApp with the object id of the class as the only differentiator:

[image: Test Results]

I want to output a custom string as either the test method name or the parameters so in Jenkins I can easily see what test case broke the tests.

I have tried a creating an Annotation Listener that implements `IAnnotationTransformer`, but when I executed the `annotation.setTestName("test")` it had no effect on the results output.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried a `toString()` impl on `data_class`?  Aside, `data_class` isn't the greatest class name.  Class names in java are, by convention, capitalized and CamelCase.  e.g.: `MyClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the toString for your data_class class method.

```
 public String toString(){
     return this.name;
 }
```

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of this but it works for my case.  Thanks!
I was hoping to determine if there is a way to set arbitrary names.  For instance if I am sending in two objects, and need to set the name based on both of them, or if I can't change the toString method.

Comment: AFAIK can't have one across multiple objects, either you can wrap both objects with a single class i that case, else have toString of both classes to some meaningful name and testng would comma separate and club those.